# Selenium-Ruby(Canvas Application)

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium, canvas

1. How to identify elements present on canvas, as we don't have any option to identify?
2. Wherever I click on canvas area, element is identified as `"css = canvas"`?
   3.How I should click on specific area on canvas?
   4.How I can drag and drop an element on canvas area?

currently for drag and drop am using like this

```
@browser.action.click_and_hold(asset_to_be_plotted).perform
@browser.action.move_to(canvas_space, -25, -25).perform
@browser.action.move_to(canvas_space, -25, -25).release.perform
```

Comment: Am using selenium and ruby for the above queries with BDD framework

Comment: We use a canvas where I work and the devs had to put in javascript hooks so we could access elements inside it. I don't know of any other way.

Comment: Hi JeefC...Can you tell me what javascript hooks dev team had added..Can you give some examples, so that i can work with development  team, sorry for late reply

Comment: Some quick examples... we use the CANVAS as a way to personalize stationery products, e.g. graduation announcements, holiday cards, etc. We call it the configurator. One of the things we needed access to was the text and image controls. The user would come to the personalization page and type text in text controls and upload images. These actions would update the configurator and we needed dev to add hooks so that we could access the text controls and see what text was inside, count the number of images on the page, validate that images were contained in the image controls, etc.

Comment: If you want to see, go to this page and click Personalize. https://www.expressionery.com/estore/Wedding/Invitations/Modern+Monogram/prod2820624_prd.p

Comment: Hi Jeffc..Can you share some demo code, so that i can get some idea on how to implement hooks in javascript to access canvas objects.

Comment: I Just want to know about hooks in Js code, how these will help me in accessing objects in canvas area, so that i can communicate about hooks with my development team

Comment: I don't know what you are asking if my answer above didn't answer your question. You will have to provide more detail for what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Jeffc...my query how can i click canvas objects, where canvas objects are like black box to me and i cant inspect also, is there any way to identify canvas objects...from your answer am not able to get exact solution.....you told about hooks also, can you elaborate more on hooks also

Comment: You don't interact with the CANVAS using clicks. Dev adds code hooks into the CANVAS. The object model already exists... you just need to have them make it accessible to you and show you how to access it.

Comment: HI Jeefc..I came to know what you telling..I need to understand what is hooks are..how i can explain to development team regarding hooks, as even they are not aware of hooks

Comment: It doesn't really matter what they are called. Just give them a list of things you want access to on the CANVAS and they should be able to tell you how to access them. The CANVAS should have an object model that can be accessed by you by executing JS code. What you will need from dev is how to access what you want. For example, you want to get the text from a text control. They would give you the JS code to get that text. That's what I mean by hooks... the code that allows access.